# Codeigniter grocerycrud : 404 Page Not Found

Tags: php, html, codeigniter, grocery-crud

When i login to the admin page i  got the error 404 Page Not Found.The page you requested was not found.
I am tring to login to the admin page in the following code:

Controller:

```
    public function index()
    {
        $data = $this->data;
        $this->load->view('admin/index.php',$data);
    }

    public function login()
    {
        $data = $this->data;
        $username=$this->input->post("username");
        $password=$this->input->post("password");
        print_r($username); die();
        $this->load->model('admin/grocery_crud_model');
        $res=$this->grocery_crud_model->check_login($username,$password);
        if($res==1)
        {

            $this->load->view('admin/main.php',$data);
        }
        else
        {
            $data['error']="Invalid Username or Password";
            $this->load->view('admin/index.php',$data);
        }
    }
    public function home()
    {
        $data = $this->data;
        $this->load->view('admin/index.php',$data);
    }
```

Grocery crud model:

```
public function check_login($username,$password)
    {
        $query=$this->db->query(" select * from tbl_register where  username='".$username."' and password='".$password."'");
        return $query->num_rows() ;
    }
```

View:

```
  <form name="login" action="<?php echo site_url('admin/admin/login');?>" method="post">
                    <div class="col-md2"></div>
                    <div class="col-md8 lgmid">
                    <div class="error" style="margin-left:10px; margin-top:35px;"><?php //echo $error;?></div>
                        <div class="lg"><label><b>Username</b></label>&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="text" name="username" class="textbox"></div>
                        <div class="lg"><label><b>Password</b></label>&nbsp;&nbsp;<input style="margin-left:2px" type="password" name="password" class="textbox"><br/></div>

                        <div align="center"><input type="submit" class="lgbtn" value="Submit" /></div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md2"></div> 
                    </form>
```

Here in model the table used is tbl_register. Is there any problem with the model .Please provide solution for this issue.

Answer (score 1):

You **cant load view** like this

```
$this->load->view('admin/index.php',$data); //wrong
```

you have to **load without file extension**

```
$this->load->view('admin/index',$data); //correct
```

so ***folder structure*** would be

```
application
     controllers
     model
     view
         admin
              index
```

and **in Model**

```
public function check_login($username,$password)
{
    $query=$this->db->query(" select * from tbl_register where  username='$username' and password='$password'");
    $result = $query->result_array();
    $count = count($result);
    return $count;
}
```

**EDIT 01**

and in form action

Change this to

```
action="<?php echo site_url('admin/admin/login');?>"
```

this

```
action="<?php echo base_url().'admin/admin/login'?>"
```

in order ***to use `base_url()` load `url` library in `autoload.php`***

Comment: when i load like this $this->load->view('admin/index',$data);  its not working  and the folder structure is correct

Comment: remove this `print_r($username); die();`

Comment: is you controller place inside admin folder??

Comment: Yes. controller placed inside the admin folder

Comment: is there any problem with the model  public function check_login($username,$password)
    {
        $query=$this->db->query(" select * from tbl_register where  username='".$username."' and password='".$password."'");
        return $query->num_rows() ;
    }

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/93030/discussion-between-user-and-abdulla).

Comment: is there any issue in the grocery crud model   public function check_login($username,$password)
    {
        $query=$this->db->query(" select * from tbl_register where  username='".$username."' and password='".$password."'");
        return $query->num_rows() ;
    }

Answer (score 0):

remove this

```
 $config['base_url']    = 'http://localhost/ASoft/Projects/AutoGadi2Amy';


$config['base_url'] = '';
just keep empty
```